# Segue programatically from custom tableView inside collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, segue

I have two classes:

```
class FeedAndGroupsViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {}

class eventsCustomCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {}
```

... where the collectionView class creates a UITableView.

I am trying to create a custom segue when the tableViewCell is clicked. I have implemented the tableView(didSelectRowAt) function for tableView which works fine. However, I am not able to call performSegue from this function. Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your class eventsCustomCollectionCell is a UICollectionViewCell subclass not a UIViewController subclass.

```
func performSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?)
```

is a method that is available in UIViewController. So for the solution you can create a protocol in eventsCustomCollectionCell which can have a method

```
func cellClicked(cell: eventsCustomCollectionCell)
```

and your FeedAndGroupsViewController can implement this protocol and can call performSegue.

I have written skeleton code for your use case you can refer to this code and get started.

```
class EventsCustomCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell,UITableViewDelegate{
    weak var delegate : EventsCustomCollectionCellDelegate?
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        delegate?.didClick(cell: self)
    }
}

protocol EventsCustomCollectionCellDelegate : class{
    func didClick(cell:EventsCustomCollectionCell)
}

class FeedAndGroupsViewController: UIViewController,EventsCustomCollectionCellDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource{
var collectionView : UICollectionView!
var yourArrayForCollectionView = [String]()

func didClick(cell:EventsCustomCollectionCell){
    if let index = collectionView.indexPath(for:cell){
        let object = yourArrayForCollectionView[index.row]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Your segue identifier", sender: object)
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Your cell reuse id", for: indexPath) as! EventsCustomCollectionCell
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return yourArrayForCollectionView.count
}
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried your solution, but it seems like I am not able to call the collectionViewCell's delegate in the function cellForItemAt.

Comment: You have to call the delegate method in didSelectRowAt of UITableViewDelegate in your UICollectionViewCell. I have updated my code.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This had me spinning my wheels for some time. In my case, I have a UITableViewCell with a UICollectionView inside of it. The table view cell is holding the array of items. I wasn't able to access those items inside of the ViewController for the specified index. Also, not using storyboards, so rather than `performSegue(withIdentifier: "Your segue identifier", sender: object)` I used `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)`

Here's what ended up working for me. I had to actually pass the object in the protocol function.

```
protocol NearbyTableViewCellDelegate : class{
    func didClick(cell: EatsItemNearbyTableCell, eat: Eats)
}


 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let eat = nearByEats[indexPath.row]
        delegate?.didClick(cell: self, eat: eat)
    }
```

In the ViewController:

```
extension EatsItemDetailVC: NearbyTableViewCellDelegate {
    func didClick(cell: EatsItemNearbyTableCell, eat: Eats) {
        let detailVC = EatsItemDetailVC()
        detailVC.eat = eat
        detailVC.currentLocation = currentLocation
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
    }
}
```